# Joomla why JFactory is often passed by reference

Tags: variables, joomla, reference

I use joomla on few projects but I haven't turned on E_STRICT on any of them before. Since I did it yesterday, *Strict Standards : Only variables should be assigned by reference* error was thrown pointing current template's index.php and breaking a bit my layouts. After some googling it seems pointless in terms of php keeping *&* in *$var =& JFactory::getDocument();* call but it looks like too many joomla codes use it that way so I am wary with simply removing the ampersand since I am not completely sure what was it supposed to do and won't it affect in any way application's behaviour. My question is - is it safe to remove the ampersand and why does this ampersand actually exist in the code if it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning by reference simply means the function can modify the variable however both the following have been deprecated as of PHP 5..3

- Assigning the return value of new by reference is now deprecated.
- Call-time pass-by-reference is now deprecated.

You can simply remove the `&` to it becomes:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
```

Comment: $var was put only for example (didn't copy/paste)in template's source code it is actually `$document =& JFactory::getDocument();`

Comment: PS: If I correctly understand & means that function can modify the variable left of the equal sign. But wouldn't it be surprising if it's unable to do so even without the referencing?